# how to avoid insertion of the two entries in database by two users which are working in same application with same database?

Tags: sql-server-2012

two users using one application and same database, when both of them are trying to insert new record at the same time on the same table of same database, they got same id. so how to restrict them from inserting such record and how to identify that both are going to save data with same id.?

Comment: That's what primary keys are for. They're unique and can be generated without fear of duplicates in the first place. Any entry level database tutorial should discuss how to use them.

Comment: Please consider reading the following articles: _[How do I ask a good question?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_ and _[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example)_. Currently your question doesn't contain enough relevant information to  be answerable and will possibly be closed as [**unclear what you are asking**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a primary key or a unique index on the column. The application should have code to pass the error from the SQL server that a primary key violation would occur if the record is inserted. You can also create a trigger to send an alert to yourself as well.